# php operations with numbers on locale

Tags: php, count

How do I format properly with php the following operations result

```
$total = 545.37;
$procent = 7;

$cashback = ($total * $procent / 100 ); 

var_dump($cashback) = 38.1759;
```

than I want to convert to german standards and I was trying to use the following

```
number_format($cashback,2,',','');
```

but this one returns `38,18`
expected result should  be `38,17`

Comment: -_- `number_format($cashback,2,'.','');`

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but did you read the documentation of number_format function? It says that the THIRD parameter (comma) is the **decimal** separator. You told the function you want decimals separated by a COMMA. And it did that. Put a dot there if you want dot, not a comma..

Comment: sorry was a mistake I want the result with comma

Comment: @fefe I almost got a heart attack :p `echo (float)preg_replace('#(\d+\.\d{2})(.*)#', '$1', 38.1759);` enjoy ...

Comment: my mistake sorry again and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `number_format(floor(100*$cashback)/100,2,',','');` to round down after the two digits.

If you need to account for rounding errors, e.g. `$cashback= 0.9999999;`

`number_format(floor(100*$cashback+0.001)/100,2,',','');`

If you want to avoid rounding errors when working with currency amounts, do all calculations in cents or millicents represented by integers.

Comment: I think that you are going to have a bad time with this floor downs. (My opinion)

Comment: Good luck to anyone using the method used for "precision", you are going to have a bad time forever.

Comment: Forget precision, floats cannot correctly represent 1/3 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use floor function:-

```
$cashback= $cashback*100;
$cashback = number_format(floor($cashback)/100,2,',','');
```